# Need to convert maven's ${project.basedir} from single backslash to double

Tags: windows, maven-3

I need to pass a directory using windows format as an argument for an exec on maven, here is an excerpt of the pom.xml

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>export</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
          <escape>true</escape>     
              <executable>${cmdl.exec}</executable>

              <workingDirectory>${cmdl.location}</workingDirectory>
              <arguments>
                <argument>${project.basedir}\\target\\classes\\publishRoute</argument>
              </arguments>

            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
   </plugin>
```

The problem that i had encountered is that the ${project.basedir} resolve to single slash:

```
cmd /c script_cmdline.bat C:\Talend_CI\talend\release\Routes\SimpleRoute\\target\\classes\\publishRoute
```

and i need to pass it with double backslash. How can I achieve this using the ${project.basedir}?

Comment: The single back-slashes are correct in windows. What exactly is the problem? Furhtermore i would recommend not to use backslashes in pom files at all.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The command line application, which is being executed by this mvn script, expects an argument (directory) either using double backslashes or forward slash. So the question will be how can I make project.basedir to use forward slash format instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after looking to several posts related to this issue seems to be that the only and effective way to overcome this issue is to use the a list of properties and use them accordingly implementing profiling. Although is not an elegant workaround gives you the option to dynamically assign files paths regardless of the OS/Platform used to run maven.

Answer (score 1):

you have one way to overload the variable or to declare a new variable to mean the project basedir
like this :

```
<basdir.home>C:/Talend_CI/talend/release/Routes/</basdir.home>
```

Comment: Yes, that's my question  to khmarbaise's comment. How?

Comment: Thanks but  it is the same as just replace the argument with static content as will defeat the purpose of using dynamic mapping. What i'm looking is a way to dynamically change the format of what ever ${project.basedir} resolve to.

Comment: i think it's not possible to do it !!!
it's a maven variable if you like to change it you must change it in the Maven core

Answer (score 0):

If the external tool you are calling can be wrapped into a script or batch file, you could pass the path to the wrapper using `${basedir.home}\...` with single back or forward slashes and then normalize the arguments in the wrapper as needed by the command. In other words: Don't try to fix the problem in the POM or Maven core (which is not practical), fix it in the shell.

You can also try this: https://www.bennorthrop.com/Snippets/string-replace-in-maven-with-regex.php